# Formula for multiple integral equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I need a formula to determine the value of $X$ & $Y$ in the below examples:

\begin{cases}
26.95 - 26.95X - Y = 26.22 \\
80.82 - 80.82X - Y = 79.23 \\  
53.87 - 53.87X - Y = 52.71
\end{cases}

Formula should always take either 2 or 3 known equations as above and be able to determine the value of both $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would need to rewrite all equations in the form $aX + bY = c$ and apply [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

In the specific example you posted, however, you can do the following manipulations without matrices easily:

1. Solve for $Y$ in terms of $X$ from the first equation.
2. Plug this into the second equation and solve it for $X$.
3. Use this solution for $X$ to substitute into the formula from (1) to get $Y$.
4. Plug both into the 3rd equation if it exists.

Let's take your example. From the first equation,
$$
Y = 26.95 - 26.22 - 26.95 X = 0.73-26.95X \tag{1}
$$
which you can plug into the second equation:
$$
\begin{split}
79.23 &= 80.82 - 80.82X - Y \\
      &= 80.82 - 80.82X - (0.73-26.95X) \\
      &= (80.82 - 0.73) - (80.82-26.95)X \\
    X &= \frac{79.23 - 80.82 + 0.73}{- (80.82-26.95)}
       =  \frac{-0.86}{-53.87}
\end{split}
$$
You can now use the value of $X$ and plug it into equation (1), getting $Y$ and plugging the result into the last equation. Can you finish it?